# UILabel in UIImageView text being cut off

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I am putting a `UILabel` in a custom `UIImageView` and the text is being cut off:

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```
//self.frame.size.width and height are the same value, self is a square
self.displayNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (self.frame.size.width - 12), (self.frame.size.height - 12))];
self.displayNameLabel.center = CGPointMake((self.frame.size.width / 2), (self.frame.size.height / 2));
self.displayNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.displayNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
self.displayNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:labelFont size:40];
self.displayNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

I set the font size large and then use [`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth) to make sure it's as large as it can be. It states:

> If this property is set to YES, however, and the text in the text property exceeds the label’s bounding rectangle, the receiver starts reducing the font size until the string fits

If I set the label.frame to:

```
self.displayNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (self.frame.size.width - 0), (self.frame.size.height - 0))];
```

Then it works as intended.

How does setting the frame to:

```
self.frame.size.width
self.frame.size.height
```

instead of:

```
self.frame.size.width - 14 
self.frame.size.height - 14
```

work?

Why is it getting clipped on the top?

Comment: have you tried `label.clipsToBounds = NO;`?

Comment: just did, no difference.

Comment: You are also reducing the height...I think the line you put has nothing to do with it.  The more important thing is you are changing to height to be 12 points taller.

Comment: er, sorry, i should have said i reduced height and width by the same amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` will only cause the label to adjust the font size until the width of the string fits within the frame. If the label is not tall enough to accommodate the final font size it will be clipped.

Comment: Yes, but your glyphs are not! When your glyphs (as many are in many fonts) are taller than they are wide the problem will occur.

Comment: ok, i think i see what you are saying. i ended up removing that line and hardcoded the font sizes. i was hoping to us this to scale it for future screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to set the `autoresizingMask` property of the label accordingly so that if the image is getting resized, then the frame of the label is adjusted properly. Or you should call the `setNeedsDisplay` on the label after adding the image on any view.